# Python socket not accepting port as variable from api

Tags: python, sockets

I am running a socket script to wait for a connection using a port number from an api response

```
SELENIUMPORT = cont["Ports"][0]["PublicPort"]
```

I am converting it to an int using a function then I'm passing it to socket but it errors with

```
client.connect(('192.168.33.10',SELENIUMPORT))

socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: is anything listening on the other side?

Comment: Yes. When I hard code the IP as `client.connect(('192.168.33.10',32840))` it works

Comment: then SELENIUMPORT is not what you think it is.

Comment: @programiss In that case have you printed out the value of SELENIUMPORT

Comment: It prints the port number. At first I was getting `TypeError: an integer is required` but after converting to int it errors

Comment: This is the output of a print of the port and connection response with hardcoded port `32824
True`

Comment: I am running through docker so everytime I run the script it starts a new selenium server at a new port. That was an example from earlier with an older port

Answer (score 0):

ECONNREFUSED (111)

Connection refused. This error can occur during an attempt to connect a TCP socket. It is reported when a reset or an unexpected SYNC message is received.

I pretty sure that you are going to have to put that in  `try` loop and wait for the other end to be listening.

Edit:
From your comments you are going to have to print out the SELENIUMPORT at the same time that you have that port number from the program that is supposedly listening to check that they are identical each time.
Arguably, testing by adding let's say 10 to the port number should give you an identical error, ie nothing is listening on the other end.
Short of that, create a script that does listen on a given port and test against that i.e.

```
import os, socket, time
address = ('localhost',32840)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)
s.listen(1)
sc, client_address = s.accept()
while True:
    print ("Connection made ", client_address)
    n = 1
    try:
        data_recv = sc.recv(4096)
        if len(data_recv) > 0:
            print ("Received ", data_recv,n)
    except:
        print ("Disconnect")
        break
```

Try running that and get your connection challenged code to connect to it or run something like:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
address = ('localhost',32840)
s.connect(address)
s.sendall('mystuff')
```